# audio interface for android application

Tags: android, audio, text-to-speech

I have developed an android application. The application changes the focus on set of buttons periodically,and using a select button the text of the button currently having focus is selected. Now i need to add audio interface so that when the focus is on a particular button it need to be spoken to the user. Please tell me the ways to accomplish it. Any sample source codes/ links are appreciated

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion you need the Text-to-Speech feauture (TTS), Android supports it.
Read the the [offical TTS documentation](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/tts.html).

I hope it helps!